# Trying to run RExcel. Keep getting error about 'no R processes'

Tags: r

I downloaded and installed RExcel from here.

```
http://rcom.univie.ac.at/download.html
```

I installed 'rscproxy' in R.  I tried to installed both 'statconnDCOM' and 'rcom with statconnDCOM'.  In both cases i got this message:

```
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘statconnDCOM’ is not available (as a binary package for R version 3.1.3)
```

I'm guessing that's why I get this error:
'There seems to be no r process to connect Excel' when I try to check the server.

On the RExcel site, it says 'RExcel 3.2.16 (and later versions) require R 2.15.0 (or later)'.  I have R version 3.1.3, so I would expect this to work, but I keep getting that message about the R server.

Can someone help me get this straightened out?

Comment: have you followed [installation instructions](http://homepage.univie.ac.at/erich.neuwirth/php/rcomwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:how_to_install)

Comment: The statconnDCOM installer is an .exe file. Very possibly not an R package,  which are generally .zip files.

Comment: That link worked.  Thanks a lot!